# Distance raster from polygon features

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, distance

I have a dataset of buildings as polygons in Qgis 2.14 (image below).

I'd like to create a raster of distance from these features (ideally with arbitrary cell dimension), for which each cell expresses the minimum distance from the closest polygon.

I've searched through all processing tools (GDAL, GRASS, SAGA), but didn't find anything that could make this kind of operation.

Is there any solution?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. "Rasterize" with `A fixed value to burn` of 1
2. "Proximity Raster distance"

[image]

Comment: Thank you!
It worked.